# How to group by a calculated average

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have the statement

```
SELECT ItemName, CONCAT(FirstName, ' ' , LastName) as AuthorName, Avg(DifRating) as 'AvgDifficuilty', Avg(EnjRating) as 'AvgEnjoyment', I.ItemID, A.AuthorID
        FROM Rating R
        INNER JOIN Item I ON R.ItemID = I.ItemID
        INNER JOIN Author A ON I.AuthorID = A.AuthorID
        INNER JOIN UserAccount UA ON A.UserID = UA.UserID
        GROUP BY R.ItemID
```

but the problem is that instead of having the AvgDifficuilty and AvgEnjoyment being seperate it is oddly combining the maths of them but displaying them seperate

so if for example i have the vales 3 and 4 for the DifRatings and also a 3 and 4 for the EnjRatings i get a 3.5 for the Dif which is correct but then a 4 for the Enj.

And I have to group by ItemID so I think the solution to this problem is to also group buy the 2 averages so that they are calculated correctly but I cant seem to get it to be able to group by an average number

I have tried

```
GROUP BY R.ItemID, Avg(DifRating)
```

and

```
GROUP BY R.ItemID, AvgDifficuilty
```

but both just give errors so I don't know how to do it.

**TLDR: how do i group by an average number**

Any help would be greatly appreciated and sorry if I have done a bad job explaining ill try answer any questions/fill in blanks cause i dont know if what i want is even possible.

Comment: I included the MySQL tag because this query would not run on any other flavor of RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compute the averages from the `Rating` table first, before you them to the other tables:

```
SELECT i.ItemName,
       i.ItemID,
       a.AuthorID,
       CONCAT(a.FirstName, ' ', a.LastName) AS AuthorName,
       t.AvgDifficulty,
       t.AvgEnjoyment
FROM
(
    SELECT ItemID,
           AVG(DifRating) AS AvgDifficulty,
           AVG(EnjRating) AS AvgEnjoyment
    FROM Rating
    GROUP BY ItemID
) t
INNER JOIN Item i
    ON t.ItemID = i.ItemID
INNER JOIN Author a
    ON i.AuthorID = a.AuthorID
INNER JOIN UserAccount ua
    ON a.UserID = ua.UserID
```

Comment: Yes thank you so much i didn't know it was possible to sub query like this